# Visual Studio build error due to failure to delete binary file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# Windows Forms application (lets call it App.exe) which is failing to build for a strange reason . This appears to be due to a bug in Visual Studio 2010. I am not in a position to upgrade to VS2012.

- After a code change and build, VS2010 seems to fail to delete the old binary App.exe.
- It then discovers some of the types in the old binary and throws the error "the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties".
- The types shown in the error message are identical. So I think its finding the types in both the old binary and the source code.
- When I clean and rebuild, or delete the old binary App.exe from disk, the build succeeds

Here is an example of the type of error that I am running into:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:     
'App.Namespace.Class.Method(System.Type)' 
and 
'App.Namespace.Class.Method(System.Type)'
```

I would be grateful for any help in solving this problem.

**EDIT**

This was caused by the the App having an assembly reference to itself. Not sure how that happened, but when I removed the reference the problem was fixed.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the bin and obj folders? (Make a backup first).

Comment: how did you manage that :) I was going to say 'two versions' of the lib

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new project? Just make a new project and add your existing files.
You could also try to delete the bin and obj folders in your solution folder.

**UPDATED**

This is kind of a automated hack but it should work.
Right click your project and open up its properties. Goto Build Events and enter the following in the Pre-build event command line:

```
cd $(TargetDir)
del *.exe
```

This will delete the old binary file before building.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried deleting bin and obj folders, doesn't help. Also App.exe has 1000s of lines of code and 100s of files, would not be fun to recreate the project file.